# will mousemove always be fired before mouseup?

Tags: javascript, mousemove, mouseup

Is mousemove always fired with the most recent coordinates before mouseup? Or phrased differently: Are the coordinates of the mmouseupevent the same as the last mousemoveevent?

Background:

When using coordinates of the mousemove event often I find myself calling the handler of the mousemove event one more time from the mouseup handler so I can be sure, that I got the most recent coordinates (example: dragging elements). Is that needed? Or can I rely on the fact that the mousemove event is **always** called before the mouseup event so I dont need to explicitely handle the case that the mousemove coordinates outdated when the mouseup occurs?

Comment: `mousemove` => Gives current position of mouse pointer always.

Comment: If the mouse is moving before a mouseup occurs, then the mousemove event is also fired before mouseup. But, you can't rely on the coordinates on mousemove to be up-to-date. Though the event fires in a very small interval, mouse moves also between the fires.

Comment: Not quite sure to understand the issue here... mouseup does expose the coordinates information relative to when this event fired, why don't you use this? Even if we assume a theoretical case where the event loop is busy for super long time, if the user releases the button on top of element A, then move their mouse over element B, the next mousemove event you'll get would point to element B, while user had released it over element A. mouseup's coords would point to A, do you really want B as you are currently asking for?

Comment: @Kaiido the only question I am asking here is if I can rely on the fact that the last mousemove event BEFORE the mouseup has the same coordinates. I think you are thinking way to complicated here

Comment: Then not really no, as @Teemu pointed out, mousemove event fires at a certain rate (animation frame's rate in Chrome and FF), if your mouseup event fires in between two such events, then it's possible no mousemove event would have the correct coords of the mouseup event, but that shouldn't matter since this mouseup will have its own coords exposed. Also, if you want an higher rate (device one), then you could hook to pointerrawupdate event, but that's not really well supported yet.

Comment: @teemu make it an answer and I will gladly except it :)